# R - Simple loop not working: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level

Tags: r, loops, break, microbenchmark

I know this is probably an easy question but I am trying my best to learn and improve. When I try this code, it gives me the error: "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level". Could someone suggest why and help me? Thank you really much.

```
x_1 <- rnorm(100)
x_2 <- rnorm(10000)
x_3 <- rnorm(1000000)

to_evaluate <- list(x_1, x_2, x_3)

speed_test <- for (i in to_evaluate) {
  microbenchmark(mean_loop(i), mean_mat(i), mean(i))
} 
print(speed_test)
```

Code for mean_loop and mean_mat:

```
x <- c(1:11)

mean_loop <- function(x) {
  
  sum_of_x <- 0
  
  for(i in x){
    sum_of_x <- sum_of_x + x[i]
  }
  
  mean_of_x <- sum_of_x/length(x)
  return(mean_of_x)
}

mean_mat <- function(x) {
sum(diag(length(x))%*%x)/length(x)
}
```

The function `microbenchmark` (from the package `microbenchmark`) lets you measure how fast code runs. If you give it code to evaluate, it will evaluate it 100 times, and return summary statistics on how long the code took to run. If you give it multiple expressions, it will do this for each expression.

Comment: Maybe try using `for (i in length(to_evaluate)`. Also, have you considered the use of `lapply`? i.e. `lapply(to_evaluate, function(x) microbenchmark(mean_loop(x), mean_mat(x), mean(x)))`? Could you add the packages you are using for the `microbenchmark()`, `mean_loop()` and `mean_mat()` functions?

Comment: Thank you! I added the code. unfortunately neither of your solutions worked for me, but thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using the function definitions from the question -

```
x_1 <- rnorm(10)
x_2 <- rnorm(100)
x_3 <- rnorm(1000)
library(microbenchmark)
to_evaluate <- list(x_1, x_2, x_3)

result <- vector('list', length(to_evaluate))

for (i in seq_along(to_evaluate)) {
  val <- to_evaluate[[i]]
  result[[i]] <- microbenchmark(mean_loop(val), mean_mat(val), mean(val))
} 

result

#[[1]]
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr   min     lq    mean median    uq     max neval cld
# mean_loop(val) 2.818 3.2495 7.62632  4.204 5.847  41.214   100   a
#  mean_mat(val) 2.547 2.9765 7.90376  3.571 4.940  93.155   100   a
#      mean(val) 1.896 2.1700 6.59605  2.818 4.204 116.467   100   a

#[[2]]
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
 #mean_loop(val) 49.368 89.8705 92.81099 92.820 99.6505 179.400   100   c
 # mean_mat(val) 18.968 50.7335 55.61163 52.987 55.5770 141.363   100  b 
 #     mean(val)  2.090  2.2815  3.87982  2.803  3.3115  33.779   100 a  

#[[3]]
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min        lq       mean   median        uq       max neval cld
# mean_loop(val) 1359.527 1511.9295 3312.36578 1835.326 2970.1350 16455.048   100   b
#  mean_mat(val) 1713.178 2155.3815 4032.53143 2352.858 2739.6650 19783.264   100   b
#      mean(val)    3.708    4.6695   16.39451   14.881   21.8355   162.184   100  a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `lapply()`** you could do:

```
speed_test <- lapply(to_evaluate, function(x) microbenchmark(mean_loop(x), mean_mat(x), mean(x)))
print(speed_test)
```

Example:

```
# had to remove x_3 to overcome a crash not linked with the use of a loop or lapply, see the Note at the end of the post
x_1 <- rnorm(100)
x_2 <- rnorm(10000)
to_evaluate <- list(x_1, x_2)

library(microbenchmark)

speed_test <- lapply(to_evaluate, function(x) microbenchmark(mean_loop(x), mean_mat(x), mean(x)))
```

Output:

```
> print(speed_test)

[[1]]
Unit: microseconds
         expr  min    lq   mean median   uq    max neval cld
 mean_loop(x) 35.3 36.05 67.174  36.85 37.3 3000.9   100   a
  mean_mat(x) 19.7 20.25 38.090  20.60 20.9 1761.0   100   a
      mean(x)  2.0  2.30  2.793   2.70  2.9   13.8   100   a

[[2]]
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 mean_loop(x) 126214.8 139520.40 211537.906 182460.50 245618.95 463139.9   100  b 
  mean_mat(x) 275451.1 314082.60 337446.084 340836.75 358470.35 411152.0   100   c
      mean(x)     16.7     20.15     31.192     33.35     35.35     82.0   100 a
```

**Note:**

Whether I use loop of lapply, on my computer, I encounter a performance issue not related to your question. *I.e.* even this is not working for me `microbenchmark(mean_loop(to_evaluate[[3]]), mean_mat(to_evaluate[[3]]), mean(to_evaluate[[3]]))` while the others are running fine (with `to_evaluate[[1]]` and `to_evaluate[[2]]`).

Comment: Hi Paul! Thank you! I tried but the error "no loop for break/next, jumping to top level" keeps popping up. I think the error is actually inside microbenchmark().

Comment: @CeciliaBonucchi The code presented in this answer does work for me and produce the shown output :/ However, for some reasons, if I include the custom functions `mean_mat()` and `mean_loop()` it crashes but for another reason than the one you are pointing out

Comment: I just tested and got the same reasoning. I think microbenchmark cannot perform multiple functions at a time. Do you think I need a nested lapply or a nested loop? Could you try to help me build it? Thank you so much

Comment: @CeciliaBonucchi, Ronak solved your loop problem I think so I focused my answer on an idea with `lapply` however I can not test it due to another problem that is not related to your question. I seems like `microbenchmark()` actually can process multiple functions at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort you put in helping me! I'll try to get your code (which is truly interesting) to work also for x_3! Thanks again!!

Comment: @CeciliaBonucchi you are welcome, in fact the code should work with `x_3` without any change, it is just due to my computer's limits. Even Ronak's code do not work on my computer :/